# How does MVC know about Dependency Injection in controller constructors, ASP.NET Core2

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection

I'm starting to write controllers for ASP.NET Core 2. I am now adding an ILogger to the constructor of one of these controller classes. It occurred to me that since I don't directly create instances of these classes based on Controller, somehow the application must be aware of the signatures of the constructor. How does that work? Is there a list of signature conventions I should be using?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be aware of the signatures ahead of time. It can examine them on the fly using reflection. If you're curious, ASP.NET Core is open source and you can [examine it on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home), or most other DI libraries.

Comment: Since MVC has the controllers wired up for Dependency Injection, it will automatically instantiate the controllers and inject the things that are registered with the container. It doesn't matter whether its a DbContext, or an ILogger or anything else. So long as it's registered with the container, it can be injected. You seem to not quite get the concept of DI. I suggest watching [Deep Dive into Dependency Injection and Writing Decoupled Quality Code and Testable Software](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412).

Comment: Ha! I definitely need some work with the concept of DI. I appreciate the link and will watch.

Comment: OK. I think I understand the "why" of DI, just struggling with the "how". For a controller, which is instantiated by the container, the DI objects are passed from the container to the controller. When I write the controller's constructor, is the order of parameters (especially when there are more than one DI objects) important or will that be resolved at runtime?

Comment: The order is not important. The DI framework will use reflection to examine the constructor parameters. If it sees a type that is registered with it, it will provide a value for that to the constructor.